# Postfix not signing mail with OpenDKIM

Tags: postfix, arch-linux, opendkim

Postfix is not signing outgoing mail with OpenDKIM despite giving no errors.

My `main.cf file`

```
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
inet_protocols = ipv4
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
shlib_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
myhostname = mail.root-louis.net
mail_name = root-louis.net
mydomain = root-louis.net
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, mail, localhost.localdomain, localhost, localhost.$mydomain
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.root-louis.net/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.root-louis.net/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.root-louis.net/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sender_login_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/login_maps.pcre
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname
home_mailbox = Mail/Inbox/
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
```

My `opendkim.conf`

```
KeyTable file:/etc/postfix/dkim/keytable
SigningTable refile:/etc/postfix/dkim/signingtable
InternalHosts refile:/etc/postfix/dkim/trustedhosts
#Socket inet:12301@localhost
KeyFile /etc/postfix/dkim/root-louis.net/mail.private
Domain root-louis.net
Socket inet:12301@localhost
```

Comment: Silly question, but is opendkim up & running? What do you get running a tcpdump on the iface/port? I would also put the following into opendkim.conf - `RequestReports True`, `ResolverTracing True`, `SignatureAlgorithm rsa-sha256`, `Statistics /var/log/opendkim/stats.log`, `SubDomains True`, `Syslog True`, `SyslogSuccess True`, `UserID opendkim:opendkim`, `TrustAnchorFile /var/lib/named/named.root.key`. Update the bits that need setting for your environment.

Comment: It is definitely running, I have confirmed with netstat that it is binded to port 12301 and running so i'm guessing the problem is with Postfix, tcpdump shows no packets.